# How to approximate the number of groups?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, groups-enumeration

> How can I find a reasonable approximation for the number of groups upto isomorphism of some higher order $\ n\ $ with relatively large exponents in the prime factorization without excessive calculations ?

This number is usually called $\ gnu(n)\ $.

For example, how many groups upto isomorphism of order $\ 86\ 400\ $ (The number of seconds in a day) approximately exist ?

The supermultiplicativity gives $$gnu (86400)\ge gnu(128)\cdot gnu(675)=39\ 576$$ but his bound is even worse than $gnu(1920)=241\ 004$. Since the prime factorization of $\ 86\ 400\ $  is $\ 2^7\cdot 3^3\cdot 5^2\ $ , I think, that $gnu(1920)$ is still much too low.

Any advices ?

Comment: The roughest estimate (you probably know), $n^{n^2}$, is an upper  bound.  From the Cayley table.  I don't quite understand your post.

Comment: This bound can barely be called an "approximation" although there is no rigorous definition of "approximate". Additionally, I would be more interested in (useful) lower bounds.

Comment: I don't think this is an easy problem. For example, in c. 2000 Besche, Eick and O'Brien classified all the groups of order up to 2000 (see [here](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~obrien/research/2000.pdf)). However, avoiding $p$-groups might make the problem tractable (look at the number of groups of order 1024 in the table at the end of the paper). There is also a "[small group library](https://www.gap-system.org/Packages/smallgrp.html)", accessible via GAP, and which is a way of accessing this classification, and also other related results (see the documentation for details).

Comment: @user1729 Unfortunately, I have no access to GAP. I tried to download it on ubuntu, but it did not work. Hence, I only have access to $gnu(n)$ for $n\le 2047$, which is not very helpful here. Is even an "approximation" hard ?

Comment: Yes, approximations (i.e. bounds) are very hard. There is a whole book on this topic.

Comment: @user1729 No, it doesn't. Where did you read that?

Comment: @ChrisCuster Why do you not understand the post? Your "bound" for $n=4$ says that there are at most $4^{16}$ groups of order $4$, whereas there are only $2$ groups of order $4$.

Comment: @the_fox Is there at least a list of the known values beyond $\ 2048\ $ I can look up ?

Comment: @user1729 You have definitely misread it. The primes referred to there are with repetition.

Comment: My "bound" is not very good, I see.  @the_fox  what I meant was that I didn't see how he was getting those estimates.  I graduallly got that he wants a higher lower bound.

Comment: @Peter No, I don't think so. We know, for example, all groups of order $p^4$ no matter what the prime is, so you can pick a large enough prime to get $p^4>2048$. But as the "complexity" of the number you are looking for increases, the problem becomes unmanageable. To illustrate: we definitely do not know how many groups of order $p^5q^3$ there are.

Comment: @Peter If you want to find out more about that stuff, you should look at [this](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/enumeration-of-finite-groups/622AC3F2907A69F82D742F60D81D9C0A) book.

Comment: Also, to get a rough idea of what's happening as you keep adding primes to $2^7 =128$, note that there are $20169$ groups of order $2^7*3$ and $157877$ groups of order $2^7*3^2$.

Comment: I would have expected a larger jump from $2^7\cdot 3$ to $2^7\cdot 3^2$. This number of groups gives a slightly better lower bound than mine in the question.

Comment: You've asked variants of this question probably a dozen time on this site. Could you at least be a little clearer? What kind of approximation do you want? Asymptotic? For a certain range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I follow here the book ["Enumeration of finite groups"](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/enumeration-of-finite-groups/622AC3F2907A69F82D742F60D81D9C0A).

You can estimate the number $f_b(n)$ of binary systems $S$ with $n$ elements (sets $S$ with map from $S\times S \to S$), and that's also what was already addressed in the comments as
$$ f_b(n) \le n^{n^{2}}.$$ It means you can have one of $n$ entries in each of the $n^2$ fields of the multiplication table. The error you make here is to neglect the isomorphism bit. One can "over-correct" that by simply eliminating all possible permutations of the $n$-elements in the former estimate:

$$ \frac{n^{n^{2}}}{n!} \le f_b(n) \le n^{n^{2}}.$$

In a next step one can include the occurrence of a unit element (and using some approximation) which reduces the number of possibilities for binary sets with unit elements to $f_{b1}$ to

$$ n^{n^{2}-3n+O(n)} \le f_{b1}(n) \le n^{(n-1)^{2}}.$$

In a further step one can try to estimate what happens when we include associativity (that's actually the really hard bit for this approach, obviously associativity is no "simple symmetry property" of a multiplication table), that would yield us the number of semigroups $f_{s}$, some consideration of the multiplications table shows that one can get

$$ n^{{(1-\varepsilon)}n^2} \le f_{s}(n) \le n^{n^2} $$.

Next one can consider the number of latin squares  $f_l(n)$, those are mult. tables where each element occurs once and only once (those are actually the group tables with and without associativity). For that one can get
$$ \frac{(n!)^{2n}}{n^{n^2}}\le f_l(n) \le n^{n^2} $$

Finally for groups one can estimate the minimal number of generators $d(n)$ to $\le \log(n)$  and then using the Lagrange and Cayley theorem one can arrive at the substantially smaller upper bound for the the number of groups with $n$-elements $f(n)$

$$ f(n) \le n^{n\log(n)}$$.

The estimate on $d(n)$ can be improved a little to arrive at lower

$$ f(n) \le n^{n d(n)} \le n^{n\log(n)}$$.

This is about where the current knowledge on the general problem ends and the [book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/enumeration-of-finite-groups/622AC3F2907A69F82D742F60D81D9C0A) starts. Essentially different classes of finite groups are then considered. For example for groups of order $p^m$ with prime $p$ one can get

$$ n^{\frac{2}{27} m^2 (m-6)} \le f(p^m) \le n^{ 
       \frac{2}{27} m^3 + O(m^{\frac{5}{2}})
     } $$

Then the book continues to regard special groups like soluble subgroups of the symmetric groups or Abelian groups and so on.