# When does the inequality not hold?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Related to : [How to approximate the number of groups?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3653305/how-to-approximate-the-number-of-groups)

Here :

https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Number_of_groups_of_given_order

an inequality is mentioned which can be written as $$gnu(ab)\ge gnu(a)\cdot gnu(b)$$ where $\ gnu(n)\ $ denotes the number of groups of order $\ n\ $ upto isomorphism.

It is explicitely stated that $\ a\ $ and $\ b\ $ have to be coprime. So, I wondered for which positive integers $a,b$ the inequality does NOT hold.

To check this, I used $\ gnu(n)\ $ for $\ n\le 2047\ $ : whenever $ab\le 2047$, the inequality is satisfied.

> Can we omit that $a$ and $b$ are coprime ? If not, what else is necessary ?

Comment: I would conjecture that it holds for all $a$ and $b$, but it might be difficult to prove this.

Comment: @DerekHolt Hi, any ideas how to bound $gnu(86400)$ ?